Can't login metro
I can't log in Metro to connect it to my emulator what should I do to fix this as you can see I have provided the image and I tried numerous methods to resolve it but still a problem

I even created a new directory in the metro.config but it doesn't seem to work

read debugging basics: https://reactnative.dev/docs/debugging, because from such an image there is not much info to do something with....

Hi! Could you show us your logs, or more valuable information regarding this problem?
